# CSS div block is inheriting his parent's attributes

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML `div` inside another `div`:

```
<div class="content">
     <div class="block">
     blabla
     </div>
     <br/>
     <div class="block">
     blabla
     </div>
     <br/>
     <div class="block">
     blabla
     </div>
     <br/>
     <div class="block">
     blabla
     </div>
</div>
```

I'm expecting to see 4 small blocks containing 'blabla' but instead those blocks are taking the whole area (same width as "content")

[image: expectation versus reality]

How can I disable parent to child inheritance?

CSS:

```
.block {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: #d9edf7;
  border-color: #bce8f1;
  color: #3a87ad;
}

.content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    width: 940px;
    background-color: White;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
    min-height: 180px;
    height: 80%;
}
```

thanks

Comment: is this the right css passage of your code ? if not, check your spelling.

Comment: Nothing wrong with his CSS. He's most likely French and translated the HTML, but not the CSS. I edited the question (but needs approval first)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every block element like `<div>, <p>`  having default 100% width.
here is list of some block element http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/block.html

if you want less width than 100%, then you should asign some fixed width to that element

Comment: Indeed, setting a small width did what I needed

Answer (score 2):

```
block{width: 50px;}
```

Give it fix width, coz all block element having 100% width by default,
Check it out Fabizio's ans also
"Fabrizio Calderan's" ans is also R8 for flexible width you can use his ans

Answer (score 2):

Try to override the property `width` in your .`block` css rule

```
.block{

  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: #d9edf7;
  border-color: #bce8f1;
  color: #3a87ad;
  width: 10%; /* or some precise value like 40px */
}
```

Overriding means writing over a property inherited by a parent. If you use a tool like Firebug in your browser you can clearly see the overridden properties and the new values associated to them.

Answer (score 1):

try to add these rules

```
.block {
  float: left; 
  clear: left;
  min-width: 100px; /* just to have some visual order */
}

.content {
  /* float clearing */
  height: auto; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

setting a fixed width could be in fact not always easy (if your labels may vary in length size you can't previously define a width of 50 or 100px ) and using `inline-block` will put those label side-by-side aligned (assuming no `<br>` is used).

Be also aware you have a typo: you wrote `.bloc` instead of `.block`

Comment: Edited the question. It's no actually a typo, it's French he probably forgot to translate (same for 'corpsContenu').

Comment: I think this kind of update should be verified first with OP just to be sure his code is right.

Answer (score 0):

Check the spelling of .bloc it is .block
JSFIDDLE
http://jsfiddle.net/Bsa3C/1/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the css you provided is for the code above, then you should give the inside div elements of content a fixed or flexible width like

```
.block{width: 50px;}
```

or

```
.block{width:20%;}
```

width is not inherited from the outside element, it is default to 100%

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to set the width, you can also try this as well:

```
.block { display:inline-block }
```